# Replace string of a file with a string of another file for matches

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I have a file `comp.pkglist` which mention package version and release. The two fields `'version change'` and `'release change'` each contain two versions in the format `'old' --> 'new'`.

```
Version Change: <old version> --> <new version>
Release Change: <old version> --> <new version>
```

```
$ cat comp.pkglist
Package list:   nss-util-devel-3.28.4-1.el6_9.x86_64
Version Change: 3.28.4 --> 3.36.0
Release Change: 1.el6_9 --> 1.el6

Package list:   tzdata-2018e-3.el6.noarch
Version Change: 2018e --> 2018g
Release Change: 3.el6 --> 1.el6
```

For every package name I need to search in `/tmp` directory and replace its version from old version to new version and old release to new release:

```
$ grep -ri -n tzdata /tmp/.
/tmp/core.pkglist:578:package tzdata                  2018e       3.el6    arch noarch

$ sed -i '578s/2018e/2018g/' /tmp/core.pkglist   # To replace '2018e by 2018g in 578th line.
```

How can I make it work for all packages in the `comp.pkglist` file to replace its old version to new version and old release to new release in any file under the directory `/tmp`.

Comment: In general it is expected of you to solve your problem yourself but ask for help on the way. You seem to specify a problem and ask for an implementation. Please describe what has been done to solve the problem and where you struggled.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided expected output anyway this sed will place with new version on all  `-->` lines:

```
sed -i 's/[^ ]\{1,\} --> \(.\{1,\}\)$/\1/'
```

Test:

```
$ cat comp.pkglist
Package list:   nss-util-devel-3.28.4-1.el6_9.x86_64
Version Change: 3.28.4 --> 3.36.0
Release Change: 1.el6_9 --> 1.el6

Package list:   tzdata-2018e-3.el6.noarch
Version Change: 2018e --> 2018g
Release Change: 3.el6 --> 1.el6

$ sed 's/[^ ]\{1,\} --> \(.\{1,\}\)$/\1/' comp.pkglist
Package list:   nss-util-devel-3.28.4-1.el6_9.x86_64
Version Change: 3.36.0
Release Change: 1.el6

Package list:   tzdata-2018e-3.el6.noarch
Version Change: 2018g
Release Change: 1.el6
```

Comment: package tzdata                  2018e       3.el6    arch noarch   While searching 'tzdata' in /tmp directory I got above entry in the file /tmp/core.pkglist , now what I want is :  package tzdata                  2018g       1.el6    arch noarch . It should take 2018g and 1.el6 values from source file ie.  comp.pkglist and edit in the file /tmp/core.pkglist

Comment: Nice. For those who hate leaning toothpick syndrome, you can use `-E` for extended syntax and simplify it down to `sed -iE 's/[^ ]{1,} --> (.{1,})$/\1/'` or even `sed -iE 's/[^ ]+ --> (.+)$/\1/'`.